# Get element value in Selenium webdriver ruby script

Tags: javascript, ruby, selenium, automation, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to put some asserts by getting value and then comparing them.
But, the get value statement always returns nil.

Desired value:-

```
<span class="contractSalesPrice.contractSalesPrice">$314,507.30</span>
```

I tried following ways: -

```
element1 = browser.find_element(:css,"#total > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(4) > span")

browser.execute_script("return arguments[0]", element1)

browser.find_element(:css,"#total > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(4) > span").attribute('value')

browser.find_element(:css,"#total > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(4) > span").value
```

What could be wrong?

Pls help, Thank You in advance.

Abhishek

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`#text`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver/Element.html#text-instance_method) method.

```
browser.find_element(:css,"#total > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(4) > span").text
```

[`attribute`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver/Element.html#attribute-instance_method) method is used to get the value of *attributes* of *HTML* elements. In your case, there is no attribute called `'value'` in `span` element, thus the method returns `nil`. For more information read the documentation I linked.